# Adding delivery address to woocommerce new order email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress website with Woocommerce installed.
How can I add delivery address to the 'new order' email sent to admins? I have found how to edit this email but can't find the correct syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try putting  this snippet in you active themes functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wc_add_shipping_details_to_admin_emails', 15, 2 );
function wc_add_shipping_details_to_admin_emails( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    if ( $is_admin_email ) {
        <p><?php echo $order->get_formatted_shipping_address(); ?></p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently testing, I have changed the syntax slightly as it was erroring.

Comment: Ping back if any issues

Answer (score -1):

In the dashboard go to Woocommerce -> Settings -> Emails and then click on the gear button in the new order email column. There will be a field to input the address. You can input multiple emails in this field, just separate them with a comma.